# Trouble with inserting JavaScript statement

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, code-injection

I am currently creating an android application.

The aim of the application is to fire off some injected JavaScript code into the WebView that I have created within my android application. The problem that I am having is that the action that has been injected doesn't work.

You should also be aware that the html page that I am loading has been created locally. aim of the application is to have a toast message display.The code listing is below:

```
//uses javascript that is in the local HTML file

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
private WebView myWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    String test= "test";

    String javascript ="javascript:document.addEventListener('click', function(){Android.showToast(toast)})";
   myWebView.loadUrl(javascript);
   myWebView.loadUrl(URL);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `toast` variable injected in the `showToast` method defined ? Your problem may be that this variable isn't accessible in the scope of your javascript callback.

Comment: The declaration for the show toast is at the bottom. I know the code works because it works when I initiate in from within the HTML. However, what I want to do is have it inject through the java and run that way.

Comment: I did not ask for the declaration of the `showToast` method, but for the definition of the `toast` variable your passing to `showToast`. I suppose this variable is declared and defined in your javascript code, but wanted to know where (i.e can you post the relevant parts of your javascript code ?).

Comment: Sorry my mistake. There isn't a proper definition for the toast variable.  public void showToast(String toast) Doesn't that define it. I know the toast bit works so I think its to do with the actual javascript. the Specific line is: "javascript:document.addEventListener('click', Android.showToast)";

Comment: @Sztucki can provide a jsfiddle example with the final html output.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: hope this works never used it before http://jsfiddle.net/X7E3N/

Comment: That just shows the html there is a blank function in there. when i have it run the showToast() there is produces the little toast message as shown in my java code above. The problem is that when I try to do the same thing within java it does not work

Comment: That doesn't either. The other thing that disproves this is that when the same function is imbedded into the HTML it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation.

The `toast` variable might not be defined in the scope of your callback. Also, you are missing two semicolons, one right after calling the `showToast` method, and the other one at the end of the `addEventListener` method which results in a syntax error.

Finally, you are loading the Javascript code *before* loading the page, which gets it invalidated. You should be injecting your javascript code *after* the webpage has finished loading such as in the below example.

I've taken your example and rewrote it in a custom app to make sure it was working. Here's what I've written :

**Android :**

```
// Registering the JS interface
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSInterface");
// Waiting for the page to be fully loaded, and injecting the JS code
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(INJECTED_CODE);
    }
});
// Load your custom url
mWebView.loadUrl(YOUR_ACTUAL_URL);

/**
 * Interface between Java and Javascript.
 */
public class JSInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Log.d("debug", "I got : " + toast);
    }
}
```

**Injected javascript :**

```
public static final String INJECTED_CODE = "javascript:"
        + "(function() { "
            + "document.addEventListener('click', function(){JSInterface.showToast('Hello Android !');});"
        + "})()";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call that JS code before loading your html page.
I would guess that the document object is not ready.

Change your event listener and bind to the window
From:

```
String javascript ="javascript:document.addEventListener('click', function(){Android.showToast(toast)})";
```

To:

```
String javascript ="javascript:window.addEventListener('click', function(){Android.showToast(toast)})";
```

And you should get a result. If not what is logcat spitting out when you click?

*EDIT: Just saw Halim Qarroums onPageFinished solution, that is probably a better one in your case.*